# Pointer as function argument receives memory address (C)

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments, memory-address

I wrote some code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    int a_function(int *a, int a_length, int *returned_address)
    {
        returned_address=a+a_length-1;
        return 0;
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        int n=5;
        int *a;
        int *address=NULL;
        a=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(*a));
        a_function(a,n,address);
        printf("%p",address);
        return 0;
    }
```

The expected result is that the pointer 'address' point to a block of memory at the address of a+4. But the result was that the pointer 'address' still pointed to NULL (the printed result on the screen was like '00000000'). However, when I started debugging, inside 'a_function' the 'returned_address' did point to the memory block at a+4. What am I missing?

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family.

Comment: If you want to change the value stored in a pointer variable in the calling function from within a function, you have to pass a pointer to the pointer to the called function.  Hence, you need `int **returned_address` as the third parameter, and `&address` as the third argument to the call.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I got your answer now, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

In c, arguments are passed by value. When you pass a pointer to a function then its address is copied to the function parameter. Only the modification to the content of the location that pointer points to is seen to the caller. It means that that parameter `returned_address` can point to other location.

So, `returned_address=a+a_length-1;` makes `returned_address` to point to a new location, i.e, its content is overwritten by new assignment leaving passed pointer `address` point to the `NULL`.

You can fix this by using pointer to pointer.

```
void a_function(int *a, int a_length, int **returned_address)
{
    *returned_address=a+a_length-1;
}
```

and call it as

```
a_function(a, n, &address);
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand the concept now. However I wonder what if I still keep "int *returned_address" but call the function as a_function(a,n,&address), will it work?

Comment: No. It will not work. `&address` is of type `int **` but your function expects `int *` type.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the value stored in a pointer variable in the calling function from within a function, you have to pass a pointer to the pointer to the called function. Hence, you need `int **returned_address` as the third parameter, and `&address` as the third argument to the call.

```
void a_function(int *a, int a_length, int **returned_address)
{
    *returned_address = a + a_length - 1;
}
```

And the call:

```
a_function(a, n, &address);
```

Note that you don't use the value returned by the function, so it may as well be of type `void`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `NULL`. `address` itself is passed by value, isn't it?

inside `a_function()`, any changes to `returned_address` is local to `a_function()`.

OTOH, any changes to `*returned_address` will be reflected back in `main()`.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank you. So is there a way to do the thing that I expected?

Comment: @V.T.T.Pham. 1) You're welcome. 2) Yes, read about double-pointers (or pointer-to-pointer).

Answer (score -2):

The function should receive `int *&returned_adress`.